# socket.io-stream emit vs on

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

The socket.io-stream documentation contains the following example for sending and receiving streaming data:

```
// send data
ss(socket).on('file', function(stream) {
  fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file').pipe(stream);
});

// receive data
ss(socket).emit('file', stream);
stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('file.txt'));
```

According to this example, it seems that we should use "on" to send data and "emit" to receive data. But this seems contrary to all the examples I've seen so far - that we should use "emit" to send data and "on" to receive it. Which is correct? And how should I listen for streaming events?

Answer (score 0):

`emit` will send a message and on will listen to the message. Now depending on where you are in the server or the client the message will go to the other side i.e. if you're on the client and you emit then the server will receive and vice versa. What you're doing here is using the npm package `socket.io-stream` which augments the socket to stream data. The idea is the client requests the image and the server "streams" it to them.

Comment: That's what I thought, but then why do they have a comment that says "send data" for on and "receive data" for emit?

Comment: I edited the answer to address your question. Hope it helps!

Comment: So are you saying that I use the "on" method to request the data and the "emit" method to stream it? It still doesn't make sense to me why they would write "receive data" over the emit method..

Comment: Think of it this way, the client emits the message to get the file with the stream it wants the file on. Then the server listens on that message and pushes the file to that stream. It is a little backwards from the way you're used to with plain `socket.io` but emit and on are used for messages. If you do the same thing for streams you'll have to emit a new message every time you needed a chunk. I think that's why the decision was made to do it this way.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful! I didn't realize that regular sockets and streams worked differently. For my use case, I am trying to send an audio stream from my frontend client to my backend server. So I need to create and emit the stream from my backend to my frontend. My front end should listen for the stream and then pipe the audio stream to it, and then my backend can read what was added to the stream. Is that correct?

Comment: Not quite, whoever initiates the stream emits the message that they are initiating. If the initiator wants to receive a stream then they'll pipe the stream data to whatever handler they want. If the initiator wants to send the stream then they will pipe their data into the stream. The example you have above the initiator wants to receive the file. Your case of uploading an audio file the initiator wants to send the file so your client will initiate the stream and pipe to it and your server will listen to the stream and pipe from it. Hope this helps